# How to Join Yahoo! Right Media Exchange as a Publisher?

Tags: advertising, yahoo, monetize

I'm trying to get involved in Right Media as a publisher as an alterntive to adsense and other ad networks. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to signup. I've tried contacting them with no avail.

Has anyone else got any idea how to get in as a publisher with Right Media to start serving ads from their network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years ago they were accepting publishers to try and compete with AdSense/AdWords. They closed down pretty quick, if Right Media is what that's become you may need a pretty large network or a website with a lot of traffic to become a publisher.

Their US phone number is 212-381-6900 or call Yahoo and ask for more information 1-408-349-3300